# Mocha test is failing but implementation works

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, mocha.js

I am trying to write a newer watch module that uses the `fs.watch` method instead of the `watchFile` approach.

So far, it works beautifully, but only when I run it outside of mocha.  I can't figure out why my unit test is throwing a tantrum, maybe someone here can?

Here is my class code:

```
/**
 * requirements
 */
var fs, path, events;
fs = require('fs');
path = require('path');
events = require('events');


/**
 * private
 */
var Monitor = function(directory, options) {
    this.directory = directory;
    this.options = options || {};
    (this.options.lazy && this.empty()) || this.walk(this.directory);
    this.watch(this.directory);
};
Monitor.prototype = new events.EventEmitter();
Monitor.prototype.watch = function(directory, stats) {
    var stats = stats || {};
    if (!this.directories[directory]) {
        var w = fs.watch(directory, this.options, this.justlookatit.bind(this));
    }
    this.directories[directory] = { 'stats': stats, 'w': w };
};
Monitor.prototype.directories = function() {
    if (!Object.keys(this.directories).length) {
        this.walk(this.directory);
    }
    return this.directories;
};
Monitor.prototype.files = function() {
    if (!Object.keys(this.files).length) {
        this.walk(this.directory);
    }
    return this.files;
};
Monitor.prototype.unwatch = function() {
    if (!Object.keys(this.directories).length) {
        for (var dir in this.directories) {
            dir.w.close();
        }
    }
};
Monitor.prototype.empty = function() {
    this.unwatch();
    this.files = {};
    this.directories = {};
};
Monitor.prototype.walk = function(directory) {
    var monitor = this;
    this.empty();
    fs.readdir(directory, function(err, files) {
        if (err) return;
        for (var file in files) {
            var fullname = path.resolve(files[file]);
            if (!monitor.options.filter || monitor.options.filter(fullname)) {
                fs.stat(fullname, function(err, stats) {
                    if (err) return;
                    if (stats.isDirectory()) {
                        monitor.walk(fullname);
                        monitor.watch(fullname, stats);
                    } else {
                        monitor.files[fullname] = stats;
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    });
};
Monitor.prototype.justlookatit = function(action, file) {
    var monitor = this;
    var fullname = path.resolve(file);
    if (this.options.filter && !this.options.filer(fullname)) return;
    fs.exists(fullname, function(exists) {
        if (exists) {
            fs.stat(fullname, function(err, stats) {
                if (stats.isDirectory()) {
                    monitor.watch(fullname, stats);
                } else {
                    if (monitor.files[fullname]) {
                        if (stats.mtime.getTime() > monitor.files[fullname].mtime.getTime()) {
                            monitor.emit('modified', fullname, stats);
                        }
                    } else {
                        monitor.emit('added', fullname, stats);
                    }
                    monitor.files[fullname] = stats;
                }
            });
        } else {
            if (monitor.files[fullname]) {
                delete monitor.files[fullname];
                monitor.emit('deleted', fullname);
            } else if (monitor.directories[fullname]) {
                monitor.directories[fullname].w.close();
                delete monitor.directories[fullname];
            }
        }
    });
};


 /**
 * exports
 */
exports.start = function(directory, options) {
    return new Monitor(directory, options);
};
```

Here is my **Working** external test code:

```
var watch = require("./watch.js");
var fs = require('fs');
monitor = watch.start(__dirname);

monitor.on('added', function(file, stats) {
    console.log("Caught Added: " + file);
});

monitor.on('modified', function(file, stats) {
    console.log("Caught Modified: " + file);
});

monitor.on('deleted', function(file) {
    console.log("Caught deleted: " + file);
});

// try creating a file immediately
fs.openSync('v.md', 'w');
```

The first test file runs perfectly fine, and I've tried both `openSync` and `open`.  Finally, here is a version of the same test code, wrapped in a mocha unit test which is timing out:

```
/**
 * requirements
 */
var watch, Q, fs, path, mocha, chai, assert;
watch = require('../lib/watch.js');
Q = require('q');
fs = require('fs');
path = require('path');
mocha = require('mocha');
chai = require('chai');
assert = chai.assert;

/**
 * variables
 */
var watch_directory = path.join(__dirname, './watch');


 /**
 * tests
 */
describe('test watch', function() {
    it('should create a monitor and run callbacks after fs changes', function(done) {

        // I had planned to implement promises that chained the three callbacks
        // but couldn't get one of them working in general
        var added = function(file, stats) {
            console.log("added");
            done();
        };
        var modified = function(file, stats) {
            console.log("modified");
        };
        var deleted = function(file, stats) {
            console.log("deleted");
        };

        // create our service
        var monitor = watch.start(watch_directory);

        // assert it is defined
        assert.isDefined(monitor);

        // establish a listener
        monitor.on('added', added);
        monitor.on('modified', modified);
        monitor.on('deleted', deleted);

        // here is a file name using the current date to prevent duplication during tests
        var file = path.join(watch_directory, (new Date()).getTime() + '.md');

        // let's create the file, then delete it
        fs.open(file, 'w+', function(err, fileDescriptor) {

            // this prints before console output from the watch.js's `justlookatit` method
            console.log(err);
            console.log("writing to file");

            // we probably don't want to try closing the fileDescriptor if the open failed
            if (err) return;

            // close the file descriptor
            fs.close(fileDescriptor, function() {
                // delete the file we just created
                // fs.unlink(file, function() { /* not a big deal */ });
            });
        });

        // modify a known-existing test file
        fs.open('test.md', 'w+', function() {/* we don't care about this */});

    })
});
```

I checked with `console.log(fullname)` inside the `justlookatit` method on the watch code, and it spits out the correct file name, matching the one generated by the unit test.

However, it then proceeds to return `false` when I run `fs.exists`.  As I undestand it, that means the file system is notifying me that a file exists before it exists, which doesn't make sense really.  So I tried adding an additional delay by wrapping my `fs.exists` method in a `setTimeout`, and that didn't change the results.  I have also tried using both openSync and existsSync, and that made no difference.

I'm stumped, does anyone have any ideas why the mocha code isn't working?

Answer (score 0):

So, the solution was to go for a walk.  I came back, looked at the code again and figured out the cause of the problem with mocha, and also identified many other bugs.

The problem was the lack of context.  The `justlookatit` method does not have a context, and in the `test.js` scenario it is watching the current directory, while the mocha test is watching a sub-directory.

The `path.resolve` was receiving only the file name, not the directory, and therefore merged it with the default (executables) directory, so the level of `test.js`, or `watch_test.js` for mocha.  It proceeded to fail to locate any of the files in the mocha test case because they were all one level below the executable.

I won't go into detail about all the other bugs, but I may come back and post the repository link when I get to a point that I want to push it online.

Answer (score -1):

You're missing the callback `return(done);` at the end of your test. Unless you call that callback, Mocha will time out every time.

Comment: done is being called from the `added` callback, which _should_ be executed by the monitor when it emits that a new file has been added, which is what the `fs.open` process is intended to handle.  Ideally I would create a chain of promises that lead to the done method once all three have been fullfilled.